# Reformatting a table with awk

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I have to reformat a number of very long tables as follows

**Original format**:

```
John Smith,Jones,Taylor
Janet Williams,Brown,Wilson
```

**Desired format**:

```
John Smith
John Jones
John Taylor
Janet Williams
Janet Brown
Janet Wilson
```

How can I do so?

Comment: Thank you very much chaos, Archemar & Costas for those great solutions! Difficult to know which one to accept. chaos' solution timed fastest, so I have accepted that one, although the time differences were not really noticeable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `awk`:

```
awk -F"[ ,]" '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){print $1,$i;}}' file
```

- `-F"[ ,]"`: The delimiter is set to space and comma. Now we have in `$1` the first name and in `$2` to the last field the surnames.
- `for(i=2;i<=NF;i++)`: Loop trough every field, starting for field 2.

  - `print $1,$i;`: print the first name followed by the surname.

---

The output:

```
John Smith
John Jones
John Taylor
Janet Williams
Janet Brown
Janet Wilson
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
awk ' { n=split($2,A,",") ;
    for (i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s %s\n",$1,A[i] ;
} ' file
```

where

- `split($2,A,",")` will split second field upon comma (,),
- `n=`  will count
- `for( )` will loop
- `A[i]` is current name (or surname)
- `printf "%s %s\n",$1,A[i]` print it together.

Answer (score 1):

With **sed**:

```
sed ':1;s/,/\n/;T;P;s/\S*\n//;t1' file
```

- `:1` mark return point
- `s/,/\n/` `s`ubstitute first comma by `n`ewline
- `T` if substitution did not execute (there is not more comma in line) pass to the end of script
- `P` print line from the beginning till `n`ewline
- `s/\S*\n//` remove word(`\S*` any non-empty symbols) with `n`ewline
- `t1` if substitution succeed — return to `1` point

or more *posix*'ly

```
sed ':1;s/,/\n/;/\n/P;s/\S*\n//;t1' file
```